# Adding a user to a role by name using arguments Discord.JS

Tags: discord.js

so I am currently trying to find out if there is a way I could give a user a role by typing the a variable name. Like, example, '!role  testrole', and then the bot will give them what the testrole is defined at. Like, 'if(args[1] === "testrole")...'. Testrole can just be defined as that, but the actual role name can just be like test. You can add multiple roles, and it will add it. '!role  hello', etc...? Discord.JS

Comment: Maybe you want `eval`. This turns a string of JS code into actual JS acide. This way, you can access the variable name in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something simple using a function to find the role name. You can do something like:

```
 const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => (r.name === args[1].toString()) || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));
```

This will either check for a mentioned role or a role name given